# set own value to ng-options and have the first checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok so i'm having the following:

```
$scope.test = [
        {"value" : 0,    "text" : "00:00"},
        {"value" : 900,  "text" : "00:15"},
        {"value" : 1800, "text" : "00:30"}
    ];
```

and in my select i'm doing the following:

```
<select ng-model="monday.morning" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in test">
```

with the following results:

```
<select ng-model="monday.morning" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in test">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">00:00</option>
    <option value="1">00:15</option>
    <option value="2">00:30</option>
</select>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is having the value out of the json as the options value.
And also have the first one selected. Is this possible like below?

```
<select ng-model="monday.morning" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in test">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">00:00</option>
    <option value="900">00:15</option>
    <option value="1800">00:30</option>
</select>
```

so basically have the value in options correspond with the value in de test array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the value you can simply set your model `monday.morning` to one of the items within your select array.

For example:

```
$scope.monday.morning = $scope.test[1];
```